# ConfigParser can't read file when using Relative Imports in Local Package

Tags: python, config, ini, configparser, relative-import

I am getting this error --

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Coding\user.py", line 2, in <module>
    from db_handler.handler import check
  File "F:\Coding\db_handler\handler.py", line 14, in <module>
    params = db_config()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Coding\db_handler\config.py", line 22, in db_config
    raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))
Exception: Section db_info not found in the config.ini file
```

This is my file structure :

```
├db_handler
|   └───config.ini
|   └───config.py
|   └───handler.py
|   └───__init__.py
├user.py
```

This is my `config.ini` file

```
[db_info]
host=somesite.com
database=profiles
user=hilfing
password=pass
port=5432
```

I am using the following code to read my config in `config.py`

```
def db_config(filename='config.ini', section='db_info'):
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))
    return db
```

This is my `handler.py`

```
import psycopg2
from .config import db_config

# read connection parameters
params = db_config()

# connect to the PostgreSQL server
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
```

This is my `user.py`

```
from db_handler.handler import check

c = check()
print(c)

#Other code...
```

I searched on Google and Stackoverflow and tried adding `.` or `./` before opening config file in `config.py` but none worked.

However I checked and it seems when I remove the relative import `.config -> config` in `handler.py`, it works when I just import `handler.py` and not the whole package. It only breaks when importing the package as a whole.

**EDIT** : I figured it out with a little help. `config.ini` needs to be placed in root dir

Comment: How are you running the code? In particular from which directory?

Comment: From the directory containing user.py

Comment: And which is the main script?

Comment: `user.py` is the main script

Comment: So you do `python user.py` from that dir right?

Comment: Print out the `parser ` I suspect it's empty

Comment: Yes @Mr_and_Mrs_D

Comment: I got it. config.ini needs to be in root dir.
Thank you. Pls upvote